# Android Expandable listview with radio button

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, layout-inflater, expandablelistadapter

Am using an API to fill up a questionnaire App in android. Am using expandable listview , based on the API I get question category (Parent)and questions(child).
Question(child) may change based on the question type.(Objective type : Radiobutton, yes or no, Text Type: Edit text).

I have statically created a custom layout XML and inflate that layout in getChildView method or expandable listview.

but when I expand/collapse the expandable list view all the radio button selection go wrong.
eg: if I answer for 1st category child, it will also be answered for some other category.

Please get me a solution for this. Do I have to create the Radio button / radio group dynamically or this is enough.
Based on the questionType i hide/show the widgets.
Please find the code below.

My HashMap value is like :

`HashMap<String, ArrayList<QListModel>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<>();`

ArrayList Contains :Question,QuestionType,QuestionId etc

Here is my code :
My Adapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<QListModel>> expandableListDetail;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle, HashMap<String,
            ArrayList<QListModel>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }


    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
//        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
//                .size();
        Log.e("VCVCV",String.valueOf(this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition)).size()));

        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.expand_parent, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.groupText);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);




        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       QListModel expandedListText = (QListModel) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);

        Log.e("ChildQuestions",expandedListText.getqList());

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.expand_child_selection, null);
        }


        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childText);
        EditText expandedListEditText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextAdditional);
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText.getqList());

        RadioGroup rgp = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        //NotUsing
        RadioButton radioYes=(RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioYes);
        RadioButton radioNo=(RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioNo);

           if (expandedListText.getqType().equals("Y/N")){
               rgp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               expandedListEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
            else {
               expandedListEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               rgp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }



        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackLight"
        android:text=""/>


            <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioYes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlackLight"
                android:text="Yes"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioNo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlackLight"
                android:text="No"/>
            </RadioGroup>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAdditional"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackLight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorFrameBLueLight"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





</LinearLayout>
```

Problem: If i make a selection in first category in all category item is selected, Do i have to manage the radio button and radio group dynamically?
If so in which method i have to do that. If I Create them  in getChildView it will be called each time i expand a category. So previous selection will not be remembered. 
Please get me a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use viewholder or recyclerview, this happens because the view is reused, thus same object is retrieved, use a sparseintarray to keep track of user selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Below code

```
public class RecyclerViewQuest extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewQuest.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<QuestModel> questModelArrayList;
    private int position;
    private ArrayList<Model> checkArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    private SparseIntArray mSelections,mDisabled;
    private String temptitle="";
    private CallbackInterface mCallbackInterface;
    private ArrayList<QuestModel> answerArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<ViewLayout> arrayList;
    private HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<ViewLayout>> inputLayoutHashMap= new HashMap<>();

    public interface CallbackInterface{
        void onMethodCallback(QuestModel questModel,RecyclerViewQuest.RequestBack requestBack);
    }

    public interface RequestBack{
        void onReceive(boolean status);
    }

    public RecyclerViewQuest(Context context, ArrayList<QuestModel> questModelArrayList,CallbackInterface mCallbackInterface) {
        this.context = context;
        this.questModelArrayList = questModelArrayList;
        mSelections = new SparseIntArray();
        mDisabled= new SparseIntArray();
        this.mCallbackInterface=mCallbackInterface;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerViewQuest.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quest_recycler, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewQuest.MyViewHolder holder = new RecyclerViewQuest.MyViewHolder(itemView,questModelArrayList,context);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewQuest.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final QuestModel questModel=questModelArrayList.get(position);
        try {
            if (questModelArrayList.get(position - 1).getSurvycat().equals(questModelArrayList.get(position).getSurvycat())) {
                holder.categoryName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                holder.categoryName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.categoryName.setText(questModelArrayList.get(position).getSurvycat());
            }
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            holder.categoryName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.categoryName.setText(questModelArrayList.get(position).getSurvycat());
        }

        holder.categoryName.setText(questModel.getSurvycat());
        if(questModel.getQformat().equals("Y/N")){
            holder.radioGroupQuest.setTag(questModelArrayList.get(position));
            holder.radioText.setText(questModel.getQlist());
            holder.layoutRadio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.layoutEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            holder.editTextText.setText(questModel.getQlist());
            holder.layoutRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.layoutEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.radioText.setTypeface(holder.questList);
        holder.editTextText.setTypeface(holder.questList);
        holder.radioYes.setTypeface(holder.questList);
        holder.radioNo.setTypeface(holder.questList);
        holder.categoryName.setTypeface(holder.questCat);
        holder.editTextAdd.setTypeface(holder.questList);
        holder.submitTextview.setTypeface(holder.questCat);

        holder.radioGroupQuest.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        //Check and Uncheck Radiobutton
        holder.radioGroupQuest.clearCheck();
        if(mSelections.get(position) > -1) {
           holder.radioGroupQuest.check(mSelections.get(position));
        }

        //Enabling and disabling radio buttons
        for(int i = 0; i < holder.radioGroupQuest.getChildCount(); i++){
            holder.radioGroupQuest.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);
        }
        if(mDisabled.get(position) > 0) {
            RadioGroup rg= (RadioGroup)holder.radioGroupQuest.findViewById(mDisabled.get(position));
            for (int i = 0; i < rg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                rg.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
            }
        }


        //Clearing and binding EditText
        for (int i=0;i<holder.inputLayout.getChildCount();i++){
            View v= holder.inputLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                holder.iconComplete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else if(v instanceof EditText){
                holder.editTextAdd.setText("");
                holder.editTextAdd.setHint("Comment here and click submit button");
            }else if(v instanceof TextView){
                holder.submitTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        if(inputLayoutHashMap.size()>0){
            try{
            ViewLayout viewLayout=inputLayoutHashMap.get(position).get(0);


                holder.submitTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.editTextAdd.setText(viewLayout.getEditTextValue());
                holder.editTextAdd.setEnabled(false);
                holder.iconComplete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            catch (NullPointerException ex){
                Log.e("NUL","Null");
            }
        }

        holder.submitTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ViewLayout viewLayout= new ViewLayout();
                QuestModel questModelResult=questModelArrayList.get(position);
                questModelResult.setResult(holder.editTextAdd.getText().toString());
                questModelResult.setPosition(position);



                viewLayout.setEditTextId(holder.editTextAdd.getId());
                viewLayout.setEditTextValue(holder.editTextAdd.getText().toString());
                viewLayout.setLayoutId(holder.layoutEditText.getId());
                arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
                arrayList.add(viewLayout);

                mCallbackInterface.onMethodCallback(questModelResult, new RequestBack() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(boolean status) {
                        holder.submitTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.editTextAdd.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.iconComplete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        inputLayoutHashMap.put(position,arrayList);
                    }
                });

                holder.radioGroupQuest.setTag(position);

            }
        });

        holder.radioGroupQuest.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(final RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
                RadioButton radioButton=(RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);

                mSelections.put(position, group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

                QuestModel questModelResult=questModelArrayList.get(position);
                questModelResult.setResult(radioButton.getText().toString());



                mCallbackInterface.onMethodCallback(questModelResult, new RequestBack() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(boolean status) {
                        if(status){
                            mDisabled.put(position,group.getId());
                            for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                group.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayList<QuestModel> getAnswerArrayList(){
        return answerArrayList;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ArrayList<QuestModel> questModelArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
        Context context;
        private RadioGroup radioGroupQuest;
        private RadioButton radioYes,radioNo;
        private EditText editTextAdd;
        private TextView categoryName,submitTextview,radioText,editTextText;
        private RelativeLayout layoutRadio,layoutEditText;
        private Typeface questList,questCat;
        private ImageView iconComplete;
        private LinearLayout inputLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, final ArrayList<QuestModel> questModelArrayList, Context context) {
            super(itemView);

            this.questModelArrayList=questModelArrayList;
            this.context=context;

            layoutRadio=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioLayout);
            layoutEditText=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextLayout);

            radioGroupQuest=(RadioGroup) itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group_recycler);
            radioYes=(RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioYes);
            radioNo=(RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioNo);

            inputLayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.inputLayout);

            categoryName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
            radioText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioText);
            editTextText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextText);
            submitTextview=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.submitTextview);

            radioYes=(RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioYes);
            radioNo=(RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radioNo);

            iconComplete=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iconComplete);

            editTextAdd=(EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editTextAdd);
            questList = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Light.ttf");
            questCat = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto_Regular.ttf");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
     return questModelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use viewholder or recyclerview, this happens because the view is reused, thus same object is retrieved, use a sparseintarray to keep track of user selection

Comment: thank you. I replaced it with recyclerview and used a sparseInt to track the user selection.Its Workssss..

Comment: Are you stuck on this

Comment: @Anirudh I have posted it